# Customize shortcuts for Git plug-in on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, git-diff

I would like to have a shortcut to:

```
Tools -> Git -> This file -> DiffTool
```

I have it installed on a machine with Ubuntu 12.04, if it makes any difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command should be `GitDiffTool`, so you should add a shortcut to your `Key Bindings - User`:

```
 { "keys": ["YOUR_SHORTCUT"], "command": "git_diff_tool" }
```